# Issue with POST in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, rest, jetty, http-post

I am trying to POST data using angular+ node j to my REST service running in jetty.
Here is the code:

```
var app = 

    angular.module("loginapp", []);



        app.controller("loginctrl", function($scope,$http) {
                app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
                $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
                    }
                ]);
                app.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
                    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'http://localhost:9011/**']);
                     }]);

                        $scope.login = function(e){
                            console.log('clicked login...');
                            e.preventDefault();             
                            $http({
                                      url: "http://localhost:9011/test/dummy/doStuff1",
                                      method: "POST",
                                      data : {email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password},
                                      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' },
                                      withCredentials: false,
                                      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                            console.log('status',status);
                                            console.log('data',JSON.stringify(data));
                                            console.log('headers',headers);
                                    }); 

                        }

                });
```

However the data which i am passing in the Request is not getting mapped to the method argument in the REST service due to which the method is not getting invoked.Here is the code:

```
    @Path("/test/dummy")
public class DummyService {
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/doStuff1")
    public Response doStuff1(DummyParam param) {
        System.out.println("Hiiiiiiiiii : ");
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

Without the param argument the method gets invoked however with it its not working.
The server file is :

```
var express = require("express");
var path    = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cor = require("cors");
var app     = express();



app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cor());
app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.statusCode = 204;
    return res.end();
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});


app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/test/test.html')
})
app.listen(3000);
```

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
  Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I had similar issue before, do you use body parser on server side ? In mozilla developers tools check out your method's parameters if you will see data you are passing there, then it has to be sth wrong on server side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes I am using body parser at node server.I see the form data coming correctly.However the statyus code says : Unsupported Media Type.I have used the same media type on client and server side if you notice in the code.can you please tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Hm, I am not so good with plain node.js, I found the solution when working with expressJS. When you are using bodyParser, you have few extensions there, my problem was solved when i used bodyParser.json()

Answer (score 0):

If you see the from data coming correctly then it has to be something with setting bodyParser correctly, I had the same problem and solved it with bodyParser extension for json file. In Express.js it looks like this.

```
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

My last guess is that maybe you need cookie-parser as well

Try to add it after body-parser:

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(cookieParser('SecretCode!'));
```

I still deepen my knowledge about express/node, but maybe it will help if not i suggest you to disconnect you api on small parts so it is easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have added the bodyParser as you have suggested but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you want you could past your setting file for node.js so Maybe i will help somehow, i think situation is the same with plain node as express, I mean order is important, so maybe you have initialized something in wrong order?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have updated the Question with the node js server file.Can you please check and  let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still i am facing the issue. :(